# coffee js with leaflet, unexpected if error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, leaflet

```
map.on "click", (e) ->
  if count >= 2
    map.removeLayer(newMarkerGroup)
    count = 0
    return
  else
    newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
    count= count+1
    return
```

Why am I getting the unexpected if statement, I think my code is properly indented?!

Comment: This code compiles: http://coffeescript.org/#try:map.on%20%22click%22%2C%20(e)%20-%3E%0A%20%20if%20count%20%3E%3D%202%0A%20%20%20%20map.removeLayer(newMarkerGroup)%0A%20%20%20%20count%20%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20newMarker%20%3D%20new%20L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)%0A%20%20%20%20count%3D%20count%2B1%0A%20%20%20%20return - it's likely your issue lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Notepad ++ was acting strange, it was immediately adding tab when it sees 4 white spaces, and coffeescript didn't like it. Just turn off that option in Notepad++.